# How can I remove iCloud data for a specific app

Tags: ios, icloud

I want to delete Pixel Gun 3D status but it is apparently saved to iCloud.

I have tried deleting the app and reinstalling but it kept the game's data.  How can completely delete and reinstall the app as new with no previous data?

Comment: It doesn't make any sense so I edited your post to indicate that the game data _is_ stored in iCloud. Perhaps you need to contact the developer and find _where_ they store the data and edit the post so that we could help you remove it from where it's stored...

Answer (score 1):

As detailed in [Apple's support article](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204247),

- Go to Settings > iCloud > Storage > Manage Storage (on your device)
- Tap on the app's name, Pixel Gun 3D and tap "Delete Data"

This is for an iOS device, which I am assuming you are using. Mac instructions are detailed on the Apple Support article.